# How to make a label in a quasar component to contribute to the width calculation

Tags: quasar-framework

I have this template:

```
    <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid blue">
      <q-input v-model="model" label="Very long label for my input" outlined class="col-auto"
        style="border: 1px solid red" />
    </div>
```

Which renders like this:
[image]

How to make it to calculate the width in such a way that the whole label would fit (but not more)?